# how do i get rid of whitespace in python3 whilst using turtle?

Tags: python-3.2

How do you remove whitespace in python3?

I am writing a program that needs to complete various tests. the program is using turtle and basically the user enters various commands and the program needs to run turtle to complete them. one of the tests looks like this:

```
forward 200
right 90
forward 400
right 90
forward 100
right 90
forward 400
right 90
forward 100
```

The last 2 lines are whitespace and my program so far can run them but when it gets to the whitespace it crashes. how do I get python to strip this whitespace and where should I put it in my code? thanks

Comment: what kind of data structure are the instructions stored in? is it a list of strings? or one long string? or something altogether more sinister? If you could include the code that loads the instructions that would be a big help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your instructions are being stored so I'll give you an answer for each of my most likely assumptions.

**it's a list**

This is the easiest one... use list comprehension to get rid of any instructions made up entirely of whitespace

```
instruction_list = [instruction.strip() for instruction in instruction_list if instruction.strip()]
```

**It's a big long string with newline characters**

```
instruction_list = instruction_string.split('\n') #make a list
instruction_list = [instruction.strip() for instruction in instruction_list if instruction.strip()] #process list as before
instruction_string = '\n'.join(instruction_list) #reconstruct string
```

**It's a file**

```
for line in instruction_file:
    if not line.strip(): #if the line is made up entirely of whitespace
        continue         #skip to the next loop iteration
    process_instruction(line)
```